# PyMySQL returning old/snapshot values/not rerunning query?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm using `pymysql.cursors` and a simplified code example that loads a row from a table and prints it every second is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pymysql.cursors
import time

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
     # credentials etc.
     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

while True:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM state limit 1;")
        vals = cursor.fetchone()
        print (vals)
        time.sleep(1)
```

**state** is a table with a single row in a MariaDb database.

Now while this is running if I fire up a MySQL client and change the table's contents, this script merrily keeps pumping out the original value; i.e. it's apparently not consulting the database(!).

I'm newish to Python and I'm definitely new to PyMySQL, so apols if this is a daft question but I have [RTM](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) a bit and it just looks odd.

Comment: Are you committing your change in your MySQL client?

Comment: Yes, my client autocommits and I've tested that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do not understand *why* this is necessary, but you can fix it by either

1. Adding `autocommit=True` into the `connect()` parameters.
2. Calling `conn.commit()` after the `cursor.execute()` command.

Seems it starts a transaction at a snapshot or something by default. I (nervously!) submitted an [issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/390) on the pymysql repo, as I'd not heard anything back here. This was closed immediately with the explanation

> It's [repeatable read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_consistent_read)

If anyone knows something better than using `autocommit` let me know.

Comment: Thanks. This saved my day.

Comment: You are a hero to me, my country and the world in general. This saved my whole week. Also I did not found any other way to prevent this bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot,this saved my day