# PyMySQL Only returns query correctly first time round

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql, database-cursor

Please consider the following:

I have a Python script that constantly checks a Database for new content by running a query.

```
def getTasks(database):
    print "Checking for new tasks"
    query = 'SELECT * FROM fosbot_tasks WHERE asked = %s'
    args = (0)
    try:
        with database.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query, args)
        return cursor.fetchall()
    except database.Error as e:
        print e
```

When the script first starts it returns all the correct data, however several seconds later it will re-run this function, I still see the "Checking for new tasks" in the console, however nothing is returned, no matter what is in the database.

If new content is added to the database where 'asked' is '0' it will not be picked up, nor if I change another already processed row (where asked == 1) back to 0, it just stays at 0 and is never found by the query.

Is there some sort of query response caching I am not aware of?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

**Edit**

Using the following:

```
def getTasks(database):
    query = 'SELECT * FROM fosbot_tasks WHERE asked = %s'
    args = (0,)
    try:
        with database.cursor() as cursor:
            print "Checking for new tasks"
            number_of_rows=cursor.execute(query, args)
            print number_of_rows
            return cursor.fetchall()
    except database.Error as e:
        print e
```

Results in:

`Checking for new tasks 
0`

`Checking for new tasks 
0`

`Checking for new tasks 
0`

etc etc

Comment: Is the indentation right on `return cursor.fetchall()`? Shouldn't it be inside the `with` statement?

Comment: Curiously it appears to produce the same result weather it's in or out

Comment: And with `args = (0,)`? (make it a tuple instead of an int)

Comment: I see
class Cursor(object):
    """
    This is the object you use to interact with the database.
    Do not create an instance of a Cursor yourself. Call
    connections.Connection.cursor().
    """
in the source code, are you certain of the `with database.cursor() as cursor`?

Comment: Hey Victor, Yes the database object is a Connection class, so it would be connection.cursor().  Thank you for your time btw. Also I tried with a tuple, same output

Comment: You're welcome, procrastination is my big weakness. How about the `args = (0,)`?

Comment: Just edited my previous comment, apologies for delay

Comment: How about args as a tuple, the return inside the `with` and a print before the cursor.execute to show number of affected rows?

Comment: Please see my edit, appears to have the same issue though

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569457/pymysql-apparently-returning-old-snapshot-values-not-rerunning-query?rq=1

Comment: I was actually in the middle of writing a comment saying I found that very post. It's solved my issue, it appears that by having auto commit in the connection, it's now functioning properly. If you would post an answer, I will happy accept and ofc award you the rep. If you can explain why this is needed as well, I'm sure it'll benefit future readers