# Python psycopg2 cursor.fetchall() returns empty list but cursor.rowcount is > 1

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am getting an issue here:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """
    SELECT DISTINCT (tenor_years) 
    FROM bond_pnl 
    WHERE country = '%s'
""" % country

cursor.execute(sql)
print(cursor.fetchall())
print(cursor.rowcount)
```

It gives the following output:

```
[]
11
```

which means that cursor.rowcount is 11 but cursor.fetchall() is empty list. I have already tried doing this:

```
conn.set_session(readonly=True, autocommit=True)
```

and this solution as well :[Click to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569457/pymysql-apparently-returning-old-snapshot-values-not-rerunning-query?rq=1)

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

**EDIT**: Just came across another thing, this code when executed first time, works fine. But executing it again(second, third, ...n execution) gives the above behavior.

Comment: Version numbers of PsycoPG, libpq and server might be relevant too...

Comment: Also, you're using placeholders incorrectly; should be `cursor.execute(sql, [country])`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Its 
psycopg2==2.6.2
python == 3.5.2

Comment: table definition too

Comment: [] = empty list  actually, the font was a bit confusing so I had to add a space just to make show that these are empty brackets, well thanks for editing

Comment: `cursor.execute(sql, [country])`
tried this too, returns the same query as in the question, results are the same

Comment: of course, that's why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel the first time this code was executed, returned the right data which means there were 11 value in cursor.fetchall() return list. after that I have run it around 10-15 times but giving empty list

Comment: cursor.rowcount = 11 even if I call it before fetchall

Comment: Sorry, pls ignore my previous comments. I just verified that `fetch` doesn't change the rowcount in postgres. `rowcount` gets updated only on running the query.

Comment: Off-topic, but please consider **not** formatting values in to SQL queries with string formatting operations manually (as @AnttiHaapala already pointed out). The correct way would be to *not* manually quote the placeholder (so `%s` instead of `'%s'`) and pass the values as a sequence in the 2nd argument of `execute()`.

Comment: yes that is the correct way actually.

Comment: What did you means by your _EDIT_? Is giving 11 elements and `rowcount == 11` or 0 element and `row count == 0` ? And when you say '_executing it again_'? within the same script and some `conn` instance?

Comment: @Arount FIRST EXECUTION: cursor.rowcount= 11 , cursor.fetchall() = [a,b,c,...] (list with 11 elements), executing the same code again( second, third or anytime) gives: cursor.rowcount = 11 , cursor.fetchall()=[] (list with no element in it).

Comment: Not a C dev, neither Postgres guru at all, but [sources](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/psycopg/cursor.h#L52) say `rowcount` is _number of rows affected by last execute_. `HAVING` could gives this kind of result (11 rows fetched, but `HAVING` exclude everything) - but here it looks like the second call just fail. So cursor is empty (because fail returns nothing), but last executed query was the first, so `rowcount` is still `11`. Is that really the script you are using? Could you provide a little SQL dump so we can reproduce the error? I suspect a big dirty `try / except` :)

Comment: example: if for first occurence you gives `France` as country, it works, but if for second occurence you gives `foo\ ` it makes a wrong formatted query - could you check that?

Comment: @Arount yes i checked that too, for available country it gave :
cursor.rowcount = 11 and cursor.fetchall() = []
for unavailable country it gave:
cursor.rowcount = 0 and cursor.fetchall() = []
well I have found a work around for the issue though. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. I figured out that,
Might be while debugging, we are allowing some fraction of time after connection has been made
#conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
#cursor = conn.cursor()

By the time we hit the execution button for the next line (which contains the query), database is timed out and it is returning empty list.

If anyone has any other logic for why this is happening please do share.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different solution, I have figured out that the problem described in the question arises when I execute it in "Debugging Mode" in pycharm. But on the other hand if I execute the code in "Run Mode" in pycharm , it returns the right expected output (a list with 11 elements):

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]
```

Not sure about the exact reason for it but somehow the cursor was breaking somewhere when run in "Debugging Mode". 
 If anyone describes the exact reason, It ll be highly appreciated.