# Python 3 Postgresql psycopg2 fetchall(), fetchmany(), fetchone() methods get empty altough the query result gives row

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to get all data from a table. Although the table has datas  fetchall(), fetchmany(), fetchone() methods get none. (I wrote print results in comment.) Also rowcount and len get 1. I don't use any ide.
What is problem in this?  I saw questions like that but have no certain answers. For example: [Python psycopg2 cursor.fetchall() returns empty list but cursor.rowcount is > 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273972/python-psycopg2-cursor-fetchall-returns-empty-list-but-cursor-rowcount-is-1)

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM sw_user_info""") 
len_cur = len(cursor.fetchall()) 
print(len_cur) # 1
print(len(cursor.fetchall())) #0
crsr_rw = cursor.rowcount
print(crsr_rw) #1
print(cursor.fetchone()) #None
totalS = cursorSize.fetchone()[0]  
print(totalS) #1
print(cursor.fetchmany(1)) #[]

try: 
    if not cursor.fetchall():
        print("--1--List is empty")   #print
    else:
        print("--1--List is not empty")               
    if not len(cursor.fetchall()):    
        print("--2--List is empty")   #print
    else:
        print("--2--List is not empty")     
    if len(cursor.fetchall()) == 0:   
        print("--3--List is empty")   #print
    else:
        print("--3--List is not empty")
    if cursor.fetchall() == []:       
        print("--4--List is empty")   #print
    else:
        print("--4--List is not empty")
except Exception as exception:            
    print(exception)
finally:
    cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

Comment: The fetch methods in a cursor object are not idempotent, they change the state of the cursor. Once you've done a `fetchall()` from a cursor it becomes empty. To fill that cursor again, you need to call the execute method again.

Comment: `len_cur = len(cursor.fetchall()) ` after this line, your cursor becomes empty. After that you're just playing around with an empty cursor so no data is returned

Comment: thanks for reply. I got it.